# this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication. please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the firebase

Tags: flutter

this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication. please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the firebase console

i have try so much things to solve this but nothing went happen

Answer (score 0):

check the same firebase project in google cloud and cross-verify SHA-1 keys in firebase to google cloud, if see any old SHA-1 keys delete them or if your SHA-1 key from Firebase is not in google cloud then add sha-1 from add credential option. if still same error then create a new firebase project and then try again.

Comment: this is not working i have done this so many time

Comment: is it happening in the release build or debug build?

Comment: it is happening in the debug

Comment: check package_name and certificate_hash values in your google-service.json is same as in firebase console,

package_name will show your apps package name
certificate_hash will show SHA keys without ":" between characters and show SHA in String Format, in some case Json file is not generated with latest Key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` keys. Run the following commands in your project root terminal window  (from vscode or Android studio) one by one

```
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

this will take few minutes then you'll be popped up with a screen similar to this.

[image]

Copy `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` keys and paste it in firebase project settings at

[image]
Scroll down to find your android app then click on `Add fingerprint`

> Note: Make sure to add both the keys, else it may not work as desired.

Happy coding :)

Comment: this is not working i have already try this thing so many times

Comment: if so, it must be issue of google services file. Remove your app from firebase console and re-add it